# How to convert str in a list to int without using int() in Python

Tags: python

The question is pretty straightforward. Sorry I am very new to this. I'm not allowed to use int().

Comment: One approach is to split the number into individual digits, multiply by their position and then add them together, i.e. from `"123"` to `1 * 100` + `2 * 10` + `3 * 1` = `123`.  Reversing the string might be useful..

Comment: Check out the `ord` function, e.g. `ord("1")` returns the integer `49`, `ord("2")` returns `50`, etc...

Comment: Can you give examples of the required input and output data? Plus if you've tried anything it can't hurt to post that too.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you are looking for is:

```
initialise number to 0
for each character in str
    multiply number by 10
    find number of character (ascii value, avaiable from ord(), - 48 is simplest) 
    add character number to number
```

Of course, you should check that the string is actually all numbers first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it for binary (base2) numbers:

```
>>> bin(12)
'0b1100'
>>> sum([2**i * (ord(ch)-ord('0')) for i, ch in enumerate(reversed('1100'))])
12
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice, Pythonic way of doing it.

```
def str_to_int(s):
    if type(s) != str:
        raise TypeError("invalid type for str_to_int: {}".format(type(s)))
    if not s.isdigit():
        raise ValueError("invalid literal for str_to_int: '{}'".format(s))
    return sum((ord(char) - 48) * 10**(len(s) - n) for n, char in enumerate(s, start=1))
```

If you don't care about checking the argument to make sure it's a string and contains only digits, then it can be reduced down to the following one-liner:

```
str_to_int = lambda s: sum((ord(char) - 48) * 10**(len(s) - n) for n, char in enumerate(s, start=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer depends on the numbers' ASCII values being in sequential order. You want to simply reverse the string, then turn each digit to an `int` and add it's weighted value to the string. So, if your number is `"12345"`, your first addend would be `5*1`, or `5`. Your second would be `4*10` or 40. Keep adding them and multiplying your weight by 10 until you reach the end of the string, and you are done!

```
def str_to_int(string):
    if not string.isdigit():
        raise ValueError("String must be a digit")
    weight = 1
    ans = 0
    for c in reversed(string):
        i = ord(c) - ord('0')
        ans = ans + i*weight
        weight = weight * 10
    return ans
```

If you can do it for one string, you can do it for all strings! Either use a for loop or the handy `map` function:

```
l = ["12312" , '32355']
print(list(map(str_to_int, l)))
print([str_to_int(i) for i in l])
```